# "Uncaught (in promise) Error: The 'activeTab' permission is not in effect because this extension has not been in invoked." in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the `<all_urls>` host permission and the `activeTab` permission but this error appears on `chrome://extensions/`.  Here is my manifest (with non-important detail removed):

```json
{
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {...},
        "default_popup": "...",
        "default_title": "..."
    },
    "author": "...",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "./some-js-1.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["./some-js-2.js"]
    }],
    "description": "...",
    "host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "icons": {...},
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "...",
    "options_page": "...",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "short_name": "...",
    "version": "..."
}
```

In my background script (`./some-js-1.js`), this is the code that takes the screenshot:

```js
browser.windows.getCurrent().then(function(win){
    browser.tabs.captureVisibleTab(win.id,{
        "format":"png"
    }).then(function(dataURI){
        console.log(dataURI);
        // do something with it
    });
});
```

It works in most places, but on `chrome://extensions/` it doesn't work - even with the `<all_urls>` and `activeTab` permissions.

To quote [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-captureVisibleTab) (emphasis mine),

> In order to call this method, the extension must have either the **<all_urls> permission or the activeTab permission**. In addition to sites that extensions can normally access, this method allows extensions to capture sensitive sites that are otherwise restricted, including **chrome:-scheme pages**, other extensions' pages, and data: URLs. **These sensitive sites can only be captured with the activeTab permission.** File URLs may be captured only if the extension has been granted file access.

I have both `<all_urls>` and `activeTab`, but still `chrome://extensions` is unavailable.  When I tried putting `<all_urls>` into the `permissions` key I got a warning that said,

```
Permission '<all_urls>' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.
```

I have it in the `host_permissions` because I want access to all of the hosts, but it still seems that the permission isn't given (or that I'm doing something wrong).

How can I fix this?  If you need any more information please ask in the comments.

Comment: @Robbi: I am not injecting any code, I am just taking a screenshot.  Does it make any difference if I am injecting code or taking a screenshot?  The docs say that `chrome:-scheme` pages can be screenshotted if you have both `activeTab` and `<all_urls>`, so I was expecting to be able to screenshot the `chrome://extensions` page.

Comment: Like the error (in the title) says, captureVisibleTab will work only if called from a listener [invoked by a user](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/activeTab/#invoking-activeTab).

Comment: @wOxxOm: Can you post that as an answer?  I am pretty sure that must be what is happening incorrectly - the `activeTab` permission was not active because it provides *temporary* access to the active tab, not permanent access like the `tabs` permission I was using!  This error was very hard for me to understand (mostly the "in invoked" part was difficult).

Comment: @wOxxOm can you explain what is temporary access? I have same problem, I put activeTab permission and in my background script added listener onMessage , which listen message from content script when to do screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You cannot inject in chrome://extensions/* <-- previous comment

I was hasty and didn't read everything right.
I have never used "captureVisibleTab" but I quickly read the specs and it seems you have correctly included the "activeTab" permission.

On the other hand, however, from the manifest it is clear that you want to inject a script into every page.

My advice (which maybe gets you nowhere) is to comment the "content_scripts" piece in the manifest then reinstall the extension and see if that error is still thrown.

Also, I suggest you to tie the captureVisibleTab action in the background script to the browserAction click or to a context menu item.

Finally, it cannot be ruled out that this API may have some bugs in the MV3 version

Comment: OK, I will try your suggestions later and get back to you with the results later when I have tried them out.

Comment: Commenting the content script did not help.  I think @wOxxOm has the answer (and you too) about that `activeTab` only gives *temporary* access to the active tab.  Thanks!

Comment: perfect, As we both suggest you, tied that api call to browserAction or a contextMenu items.